# ArcGIS GeoDataBase

Tags: arcmap

How is .gdb and .geodatabase different from each other?
I tried with ArcMap 10,10.1 and 10.2.2 but all of them create a .gdb file.
I want to create a .geodatabase file(not a .gdb file),Can anyone help me with the appropriate ArcMap version and procedure to do so.

Comment: .geodatabase files don't exist (with ArcGIS at least). An ArcGIS file geodatabase has a .gdb extension.

Answer (score 0):

A ".geodatabase" is built using ArcGIS Runtime SDK's.  They are typically consumed in offline editing applications.  This is actually a Sqlite database under the covers.

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1CC91BA9673448ECB1C59EAC22FB2F0A

GenerateSyncTask example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/html/e4e4ec8a-c9ad-4da2-a0ba-d79040a7f746.htm#ID0EBAABAAA_tab1

A ".gdb" is an Esri file geodatabase which is file based as the name suggests.  File geodatabases are consumed in ArcGIS Desktop or published to ArcGIS Server.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_a_file_geodatabase/018s0000000q000000/

Other ArcGIS Desktop geodatabase options, which are available at any release are:

- ArcSDE geodatabase (.sde)
- File geodatabase (.gdb)
- Personal geodatabase (.mdb)